# Ball trajectory inside a car with constant speed

Tags: kinematics

In a car moving at a constant speed (no acceleration). The driver throws the ball in the direction of the passenger seat. Dose the ball follows the same path as if the car is stationary or it would deviate at an angle opposite of the car's directions. If so how the the path of the ball in the car with constant speeds is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the car not accelerating, the car is an inertial reference frame and there are no fictitious forces.  Therefore, the thrown ball only experiences the force of gravity, the same force the ball experiences in a stationary car. The path of the ball in the moving car as seen by an observer in the car is the same as the path of the ball in a stationary car as seen by an observer in the car.

If the car is accelerating, the ball experiences fictitious forces and the path is different as seen by an observer in the moving car than as seen by an observer in a stationary car.

For either case (car accelerating or not) the path depends on the forces, but there are additional fictitious forces that act when the car is accelerating.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore safety considerations, and imagine that all the windows of the car are blacked out. Furthermore, assume it has a top-of-the-line suspension system, a silent electric motor and the road has no bumps. With these assumptions, how would you tell that the car is moving? The answer is that you can't. Even if there were constant acceleration, [the Equivalence Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) wouldn't let you distinguish between that and a change in the gravitational force, and you still wouldn't know anything about your speed without reference to an external reference point.

So, everything is the same as if you are in a stationary box with gravitational force pointing down. For the given problem, you are dealing with a projectile thrown with an initial horizontal velocity. Is that a problem you can set up and solve?

Answer (score 0):

For an observer in the car the trajectory of the ball will be the same whether the car is moving at constant velocity with respect to the ground or standing still on the ground. That's because both the moving car and car at rest are inertial frames of reference and all inertial frames are considered equivalent.

For an observer on the ground, however, the trajectory of the ball will have a horizontal component in the direction of the motion of the car because the ball had the same velocity as the car in that direction with respect to the ground when released. That component would not be seen by the ground observer if the car were standing still on the ground.

Also, the downward trajectory of the ball due to gravity will be a straight line to the observer in the moving car. But to the ground observer that downward trajectory will look like a parabola due to the horizontal component of velocity with respect to the ground.

Hope this helps.